# Apache not logging SVN traffic

Tags: apache-2.4, logging, mod-dav-svn

We have a windows apache server which, among other things, serves the SVN repository files.

Here is the configuration part:

```
<IfModule dav_module>
    <IfModule dav_svn_module>
        <Location /svn>
            DAV svn

            # specify the root for repositories
            SVNPath D:/SVN

            <IfModule authz_svn_module>
                # our access control policy authentication file 
                # path where policy is written for each user   
                AuthzSVNAccessFile D:/SVN/conf/authz
                SVNPathAuthz short_circuit
            </IfModule>

            # LDAP authentication
            LDAPReferrals off
            AuthType Basic
            AuthName "Subversion Repository"
            AuthBasicProvider my-ldap
            Require valid-user
        </Location>

        CustomLog logs/svn.log "%{%F %T}t.%{usec_frac}t %{%z}t | %a | %u | %m | %{SVN-ACTION}e" env=SVN-ACTION
    </IfModule>

    Timeout 1800
</IfModule>
```

The problem is, since I activated LDAP authentication and switched to HTTPS only, it seems that the logfile at "logs/svn.log" does not get any new entry; while it worked before.

Is it possible that the change of an unrelated configuration part interfered with the logging? Or did I just use a wrong CustomLog directive?

Answer (score 0):

In the end I found out that yes, changing the configuration moving to HTTPS only had an effect on logging, even though I am not sure why.

The SSL configuration in fact defined a `<VirtualHost _default_:443>` block which, once removed and moved all its configuration to root level, made the SVN log work again.